# Ember Data merge nested many-to-many relationships

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ember.js, ember-data

Consider these models:

User

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    groups: DS.hasMany('group'),

    permissions: Ember.computed('groups.@each.permissions.[]', groups => {
        // What to do here?
    })
});
```

Group

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    permissions: DS.hasMany('permission')
});
```

Permission

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

How can I get a `permissions` property on `User` which contains all `Permissions` of all `Groups`?

Comment: Don't use arrow functions for computed properties, you'll eventually need `this` and it'll be bound to the wrong context. `groups.@each.permissions.[]` isn't valid either, if I'm not mistaken. And computed properties' functions don't receive parameters.